# Average timestamp in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, timestamp, average

so in short my script currently outputs a csv with the log name, time stamp (10:38:52) and the message (Verification: SUCCESS and SendResponse: Response message).

I now need for this script to be able to calculate and output the time difference between the time stamp on the first message and the timestamp on the second message and provide an average at the bottom of the csv.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo."Location","Date Time","Result","diff" > output2.csv
( 
  for %%a in (z:\logdir\*.log) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=[+]" %%B in ('findstr /g:searchstrings.txt  ^< %%a') do (
      set var=%%B
      set var1=!var:~-6!
      echo."%%a","!var1!","%%B","%%F","timetaken"
    ) 
  )
) >> output2.csv
```

the log file contains many entries but this script should and does pull out just the following lines

```
[20110314T103852][EMVLib][5056][I000000]:  Verification: SUCCESS

[20110314T103902][CSV][3232][D000000]: SendResponse: Response message
```

These search strings are defined by file searchstrings.txt

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: are you restricted to using `.cmd` scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of PA shows the idea, but as it's batch there is no simple solution :-)

The getTime function will fail for 14% of the timestamps of a day.
Why? Because batch handles all numbers with leading zeros as octals, so a 08 and a 09 isn't convert to 8 or 9, it simply fails.

There exists a workaround with prefix a `1` and use only the remainder.
`set /a "hh=1!var:0,2! %% 100"`
`08` -> `108` mod 100 -> 8

So the complete batch could look like

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo."Location","Date Time","Result" > output2.csv
set totalVerifyTime=0
set totalVerifyCount=0
( 
  for %%a in (n.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,5 delims=[+]" %%B in (%%a) do (
      set timefield=%%B
      set timestamp=!timefield:~-6!
      set /a "seconds=1!timestamp:~-2!%%100 + ( 1!timestamp:~0,2!%%100 * 60 + 1!timestamp:~2,2!%%100 ) * 60"
      if "%%C"==":  Verification: SUCCESS" (
        set verifyStart=!seconds!
        echo."%%a","!timestamp!","%%B","%%C", "!seconds!", "start of verify"
      ) ELSE (
        set /a diff=seconds - verifyStart
        echo."%%a","!timestamp!","%%B","%%C", "!seconds!", "!diff!"
        set /a totalVerifyTime+=diff
        set /a totalVerifyCount+=1
      )

    ) 
  )
)
set /a "totalAvg=totalVerifyTime/totalVerifyCount"
echo avg = !totalAvg!
```

Comment: @PA: Thanks, but where is a failure in my solution?

Comment: no failure at all. I just can't accept it because i'm not the OP. If I were I would.

Answer (score 2):

you have to parse the timestamp and calculate the time value in, say, seconds.

This code, assuming this format `20110314T103852` for the passed string in `%1`, returns the time value in `%2`

**EDIT:** I discovered that you cannot pass the string directly, so I have modified the code

```
:gettime
set hh=!%1:~9,2!
set mm=!%1:~11,2!
set ss=!%1:~13,2!
set /A %2=hh*3600+mm*60+ss
goto :eof
```

You may then use it to calculate the time difference like this

```
set t=%%a
call :gettime t t1
...
set t=%%a
call :gettime t t2
set /A deltat=t2-t1
```

for a more detailed description of the commands used here, check `HELP SET` and `HELP CALL` information.